# python,googlegrooupsapiでmboxデータをインポートしたい

Tags: python, api, google-cloud, google-api, google-groups

お世話になります。
2つの別なGoogleWorkSpaceを統合するために、移行元のグループメールの受信データを移行先のSpaceへインポートしたく、googlegroupsapiでできるということだけの記事は見つけたのですが、pythonなどでインポートさせるコードのサンプルや公式カンファレンスが見つからず、ご存じの方がいればご教授いただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こんなリポジトリ(記事？)が参考になるかも。[Import .mbox files to Google Workspace (formerly G Suite / Google Apps)](https://github.com/google/import-mailbox-to-gmail)

Comment: @kunif さん、ありがとうございます！見てみます。